# How to filter numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to perform filtering of labels matrix (without 'for' loop), according to condition given in grains matrix, and that is: for each item in grains, let's call it i, if i[1] <=2, then make all values in labels, that are equal to i[0], zero.. After that, only two blue segments should appear in the final figure. Thanks for your help guys!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grains = np.array([[1,3], [2,5], [6,2]] )

labels=np.array([[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,2,0],[0,0,2,2,2],[0,0,0,2,0],[6,6,0,0,0]])

im = np.array([[223, 222, 225, 224, 227],[222, 224, 218, 220, 221],[216, 221, 
219, 223, 225],[228, 226, 231, 224, 228],[226, 228, 225, 218, 225]])

image=np.stack((im, im, im), axis=2)       # greyscale sample image

color = [0, 0, 255]                        # rgb blue color

image[labels>=1] = color

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your filtering logic. How does the grains array link to the labels and image arrays?

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake in my code. The correct is:  image[labels>=1] = color. OK, this is the code of unfiltered array. Now, I want to make all values in labels matrix zero, whose values are equal to grains i[0], WHERE grains i[1] is less than or equal to 2..